# Block sensitivity and degree

Tags: complexity-theory

$\newcommand{\bs}{\mathrm{bs}}$What is the largest gap known between block sensitivity ($\bs(f)$) of a boolean function ($f$) and degree of a polynomial ($\deg(f)$) that represents/approximates it?

We know of lower bound $$\bs(f)\leq c\deg^2(f)$$ for some $c>0$. Is there a Boolean function that achieves this separation?

Comment: Turbo, there are some surveys on the subject. Have you looked at them? Surely one of them will contain the answer.

Comment: I looked at buhrman's survey. Have I missed obvious facts?

Comment: Whatever's not in the up to date surveys is probably not known. Was it explicitly mentioned that no separation is known?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I will check back again.